# SQL - INNER JOIN duplicate column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

In WordPress, I'm trying to modify the loop first with posts that has a given custom taxonomy and then show the rest of the posts that has other taxonomies or don't have any taxonomy.

I need to do this in a single loop/SQL query so I can set offsets and do a load more/pagination on the page.

Here's the SQL I'm trying but it returns a Duplicate Column name 'term_taxonomy_id' error:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts AS wppost
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wppost.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id )
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id )
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'location'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
IN ( 1191 )
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
FROM wp_posts AS wppost
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wppost.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id )
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id )
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'location'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
NOT IN ( 1191 )) inn
ORDER BY wpost.post_date DESC
```

How can I give an alias to the 'term_taxonomy_id' in this case?

Comment: Don't use Select *.  you have to spell out each column.

Comment: Don't do `Select *` and only take columns you need.  If you need both, give one an alias.

Comment: As written, the query is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

To create an alias, use

```
select column_name AS column_alias ...
```

More info : http://sql.sh/cours/alias